# How to set 30 seconds interval for datetime on y-axis for highcharts JS

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, ecmascript-6

I have a graph, the y-axis on the graph must show minutes broken down by 30 seconds. I should display the y-axis as 2:00, 2:30 ... 5:30. The data I'm receiving from service is in seconds.

I would like to add time on the y-axis and point the graph according to the data.

I found an example, which has hours and minutes, however I'm unable to change to minutes and second with my desired values

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Time (hh:mm)'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                var time = this.value;
                var hours1=parseInt(time/3600000);
                var mins1=parseInt((parseInt(time%3600000))/60000);
                return hours1 + ':' + mins1;
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 76320000, 25920000, 102840000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    }]
});
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ezfrhLpo/35/)

I want the y axis to look as the below picture

[image]

Comment: Hi @User123, Could you describe the relation between the labels and the data values? If the values are timestamps, the chart will look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7gj3fqah/

Comment: I'd like to set the timestamps from 2 minutes to 5 minutes with an increment of 30 seconds? Like I have added in the screenshot. Please help.

Comment: Hi @User123, Yes, I know, but the difference between the highest and the lowest value in your data is more than 2min 30 sec.

Comment: @ppotaczek : sorry about that, I just gave in some hardcoded values, I'll change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran the example with some simple data so that you can see the results being reflected... The key was to use the tickInterval... after that, we just had to format the time to look like time (with a colon), instead of large numbers depicting seconds.

you can check the complete working snippet below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [
        'Jan',
        'Feb',
        'Mar',
        'Apr',
        'May',
        'Jun',
        'Jul',
        'Aug',
        'Sep',
        'Oct',
        'Nov',
        'Dec'
      ]
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Time (hh:mm:ss)'
      },
      tickInterval: 30,

      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          var time = this.value;
          var mins = parseInt(time / 60);
          var secs = time % 60;
          if (secs == 0) {
            return mins + ':00';
          } else {
            return mins + ':' + secs;
          }
        }
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Tokyo',
      data: [30, 60, 120, 45, 240, 360, 280, 45, 90, 180, 270, 0]

    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: I want the mins on my y-axis to start from 2:00 to 5:30 with 30-sec interval in between them. Can you please help me in configuring that?

Comment: There are 30 seconds interval in my code like you wanted... Minimum and maximum values on the axis are updated based on the data... Do you want a hard restrict them from 2:00 to 5:30 ?